# Insert variable number of rows beginning at user-specified row

Tags: vba, excel, insert

I need to allow users to specify what row to begin inserting blank rows into their set of data.  The rest of the query seems to work fine.  I'm just not sure how to incorporate this last variable.  Here's the code I have so far.

```
Dim NumRowsToInsert As Long
Dim RowIncrement As Long
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastEvenlyDivisibleRow
Dim i As Long

NumRowsToInsert = InputBox("How many rows would you like to insert between each 
row of data?")     'any number greater than 0
RowIncrement = InputBox("How many rows of data between line inserts?")       'ditto
Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastEvenlyDivisibleRow = Int(LastRow / RowIncrement) * RowIncrement
    If LastEvenlyDivisibleRow = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = LastEvenlyDivisibleRow To 1 Step -RowIncrement
        .Range(i & ":" & i + (NumRowsToInsert - 1)).Insert xlShiftDown
    Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just ask the user to tell you which row using InputBox as you did for the rest?  I changed your code to ask the user at which row to start and set the last for loop to count up, not towards 1, but towards the user specified row.  You may have to include some checking to ensure that the user hasn't specified a row lower down than the end of the document, but the principle should be correct.  I haven't tested this code yet, so no guarantees!

```
Dim NumRowsToInsert,FirstRow As Long
Dim RowIncrement As Long
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastEvenlyDivisibleRow
Dim i As Long

Do
  FirstRow = InputBox("Please indicate at which row you want to start.")
Loop until isnumeric(FirstRow) 'keeps on asking until they enter an actual number, otherwise the program will lose its mind when the user inputs a character

NumRowsToInsert = InputBox("How many rows would you like to insert between each row of data?")     'any number greater than 0
RowIncrement = InputBox("How many rows of data between line inserts?")       'ditto
Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastEvenlyDivisibleRow = Int(LastRow / RowIncrement) * RowIncrement
If LastEvenlyDivisibleRow = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = LastEvenlyDivisibleRow To FirstRow Step -RowIncrement
    .Range(i & ":" & i + (NumRowsToInsert - 1)).Insert xlShiftDown
Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose given an increment of 4 and 1 line of separation in a data of 10 rows you'd like to have the first and second groups of 4 rows, 1 blank row inserted between them and the last group of 2 rows of data left.
This inserts one row before and makes the rest of the work

```
For i = LastEvenlyDivisibleRow **+ 1** To 1 Step -RowIncrement
```

if you don't want the first line inserted you can skip the first step on the loop:

```
For i = LastEvenlyDivisibleRow **+ 1** To 2 Step -RowIncrement
```

Comment: Accepting an answer is usually done after a time, and on whichever answer, answers the question best.  Sometimes no answer suffices - do have patience.